# jQuery table sum change keyup()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code for finding the sum of all table rows, now it finds the sum on keyup. I want the sum to be already calculated. I wanted to have a hidden field like an input with a value, so the sum is automatically calculated.

Now there is an input, the user writes some number and than he gets the sum, I am trying to get the sum automatically. The number is already going to be in the table the user will not write anything.

HTML:

```
<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #E8DCFF">
        <tr>
            <td width="40px">1</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="summation">
            <td  colspan ="2" align="right">
                Sum :
            </td>
            <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
     //handler to trigger sum event
     $(".txt").each(function() {
       $(this).keyup(function() {
             calculateSum();
       });
     });
 });
 function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
           sum += parseFloat(this.value);
           $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        }
        else if (this.value.length != 0){
           $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you did want to sum change while user writes the input value. This can be achieved by changing your ready function to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //this calculates values automatically 
     calculateSum();

     $(".txt").live("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
     });
});
```

[Demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9973028/WEB/tableSum.html)

Comment: that's exactly what i needed , thanks a bunch and may the force be with you

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are already in the input fields before users enter anything, you can find the sum as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
     //handler to trigger sum event
     var sum = 0;
     $(".txt").each(function() {
       sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
       $("#sum").val("");
       $("#sum").val(sum);
     });
 });
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: tried it out but it do-sent work , maybe i messed up something but thanks anyways